# Find the text from a row and column in a table

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a table in a html like below, I need to extract for example the End Snap value under Snap Time column which is 03-Sep-20 02:00:01

```
<table border="0" width="600" class="tdiff" summary="for snapshot information">
<tr><th class="awrnobg" scope="col"></th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Id</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Time</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Sessions</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Cursors/Session</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Instances</th></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" class='awrnc'>Begin Snap:</td><td align="right" class='awrnc'>121525</td><td align="center" class='awrnc'>03-Sep-20 01:30:07</td><td align="right" class='awrnc'>167</td><td align="right" class='awrnc'>     10.4</td><td align="right" class='awrnc'>6</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" class='awrc'>End Snap:</td><td align="right" class='awrc'>121526</td><td align="center" class='awrc'>03-Sep-20 02:00:01</td><td align="right" class='awrc'>174</td><td align="right" class='awrc'>     11.2</td><td align="right" class='awrc'>6</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" class='awrnc'>Elapsed:</td><td class='awrnc'>&#160;</td><td align="center" class='awrnc'>              29.90 (mins)</td><td class='awrnc'>&#160;</td><td class='awrnc'>&#160;</td><td class='awrnc'>&#160;</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" class='awrc'>DB Time:</td><td class='awrc'>&#160;</td><td align="center" class='awrc'>              67.15 (mins)</td><td class='awrc'>&#160;</td><td class='awrc'>&#160;</td><td class='awrc'>&#160;</td></tr>
</table>
```

the required value is requested in the format : columnname_row name :

```
Snap Id_Begin Snap
Snap Id_End Snap
Snap Time_Begin Snap
Snap Time_End Snap
```

which goes into a variable called namesplit.
I am trying to first pull the column number,and row number to then print the required value :

```
dbii = soup.find_all("table", attrs={"summary": "for snapshot information"})

for tables in dbii:
    vcols=tables.findChildren('th')
    #print(type(rows))  #bs4.element.ResultSet
    #print(rows)
    #print(ti)
    ii=0
    for value ivcols:
        #print(value.strip)
        #print(value.string)
        #print(type(value))     # bs4.element.Tag
        if(value.text!=None and value.text.lower() == namesplit[0].lower()):         # this matches the column name string
            print("match")
            col_no=ii
            table_no=ti
        else:
            ii+=1
    ti+=1

    print(table_no,col_no,namesplit[1]) # correctly gives table 0, column as 1 or 2

    print("abc")
    #print(dbii[table_no])
    #print(type(dbii[table_no]))
    # Find Row number.
    drow=dbii[table_no].find_all(scope = 'row' )
    j=0
    print(row_no)
    for value in drow:
        #print("row",j,"asdasdsad:",value,value.text)
        if(value.text!=None and namesplit[1].lower() in value.text.lower() ):
            row_no=j

        j+=1
    print(row_no)               # correctly picks the td row as 0(for begin) or 1 (for end) 

    # We have Table no , column number, Row_no  .. get the corresponding value.
    fvalue=dbii[table_no].find_all(tr)[row_no] ## this doesnt work. as its a tag.
    print(type(fvalue)) ## tag ?? 
    print(fvalue)
```

Comment: There might be a easier way to do this, but i'm new to bs4 , so this what I could think of. The logic which will finally work here will have to be pushed into 70 more tables to get the corresponding value. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value from `End Snap` row and third column, you can do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '''
<table border="0" width="600" class="tdiff" summary="for snapshot information">
<tr><th class="awrnobg" scope="col"></th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Id</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Snap Time</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Sessions</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Cursors/Session</th><th class="awrbg" scope="col">Instances</th></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" class='awrnc'>Begin Snap:</td><td align="right" class='awrnc'>121525</td><td align="center" class='awrnc'>03-Sep-20 01:30:07</td><td align="right" class='awrnc'>167</td><td align="right" class='awrnc'>     10.4</td><td align="right" class='awrnc'>6</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" class='awrc'>End Snap:</td><td align="right" class='awrc'>121526</td><td align="center" class='awrc'>03-Sep-20 02:00:01</td><td align="right" class='awrc'>174</td><td align="right" class='awrc'>     11.2</td><td align="right" class='awrc'>6</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" class='awrnc'>Elapsed:</td><td class='awrnc'>&#160;</td><td align="center" class='awrnc'>              29.90 (mins)</td><td class='awrnc'>&#160;</td><td class='awrnc'>&#160;</td><td class='awrnc'>&#160;</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" class='awrc'>DB Time:</td><td class='awrc'>&#160;</td><td align="center" class='awrc'>              67.15 (mins)</td><td class='awrc'>&#160;</td><td class='awrc'>&#160;</td><td class='awrc'>&#160;</td></tr>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('tr:has(td:contains("End Snap:")) td:nth-child(3)').text)
```

Prints:

```
03-Sep-20 02:00:01
```

---

To get all values, you can do:

```
all_data = []
for row in soup.select('tr:has(td)'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    all_data.append(tds)

for row in all_data:
    print('{:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}'.format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
Begin Snap:          121525               03-Sep-20 01:30:07   167                  10.4                 6                   
End Snap:            121526               03-Sep-20 02:00:01   174                  11.2                 6                   
Elapsed:                                  29.90 (mins)                                                                       
DB Time:                                  67.15 (mins)
```

Comment: wow, select_one seems straightforward. But I need to make it dynamic so that I can vary what is printed ( avoid hardcodes of Contains("End Snap") and nth-child(3) )  . please suggest ?

Comment: @trent You can construct the CSS selector dynamically, for example `'tr:has(td:contains("{}")) td:nth-child({})'.format('End Snap:', 3)`

Comment: thank you.. works like a charm..         abc='tr:has(td:contains("{}")) td:nth-child({})'.format(namesplit[1], col_no+1)
    print("working2:",soup.select_one(abc).text)